# Searching multiple columns with Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have model Products with columns:

```
name, number, description
```

Index defined for this model looks like this:

```
define_index do
  indexes :name, :sortable => true
  indexes :number
  indexes :description
  where "amount > 0"
  has :price
end
```

Since in description can be lots of random words I want to exclude it from searching sometimes (when user clicks chceckbox 'don't search in descriptions').

I went to the sphinx page and found following:

```
@(name, number) *pencil* *123*
```

And it seems like I don't understand how sphinx works. When I execute search

```
*pencil* *123*
```

word 'pencil' is found in name and '123' is found in number and I get 1 result. But when I execute

```
@(name, number) *pencil* *123*
```

no results are found.

Is searching by columns somehow different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was all about spaces :/ 
This works:

```
@(name,number) *pencil* *123*
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only search on fields when using the `:extended` match mode - Thinking Sphinx sets this automatically if you use `:conditions` - but you're constructing a multi-field query yourself, hence why this isn't happening. Try this:

```
Product.search "@(name, number) *pencil* *123*", :match_mode => :extended
```

Hope this helps.